# Is there a memory leak in my code? (using pointers to store strings)

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-leaks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x;
    int *in, *begin;
    in = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    begin = in;
    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
        *in = x;
        in++;
        in = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    *in = EOF;
    while ((x = *begin) != EOF) {
        putchar(x);
        begin++;
    }
    free(in);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that it does.

With this program, I'm trying to store user input of an indefinite size into memory using pointers, as opposed to using `char string[255]; fgets(string, sizeof(string));` etc.

EDIT: The program doesn't crash or anything when I run it, I just have a feeling there's memory getting allocated that isn't getting freed.

Comment: We need more details about what happens and why you think there is a memory leak. Does the program crash, or misbehave? What happens?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you may want to check out [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It's memcheck tool is incredibly useful in tracking down memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have. `Free` will deallocate memory for one only integer. You have to call `free` for every `malloc` call you have done.

Also to store the characters in a continuous buffer you have to `malloc` an amount of memory at the beginning and use `realloc` if the characters you read become more than those initially allocated memory for.

Also don't forget to allocate one more character for the `\0` at the end of the string.

When you are done you can call `free(buffer)` and... Success! No memory leaks!

And the code for it:

```
/* Start with an initial size */
int size = 128;
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
int i = 0;
while ((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
        buffer[i] = x;
        i++;
        if(i == size){
           /*Do realloc and increase size */
        }
}
buffer[i] = '\0';
/* Do what you want with buffer */
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Instead of using 128, though, I am able to use 1 for the initial size, and 1 for the increment, thus allocating no space that won't go unused. Thanks again.

Comment: @Babkock: However, by reallocating in int-sized chunks, you're causing the memory allocation system to do an inordinate amount of extra work just to save `128 * sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: Realloc can be used also to reduce the amount of the allocated memory. So if there is any unused space after the while you can make a realloc with the number of total character read. That's the `i`. So you avoid reallocating memory in every character you read, because allocating memory is considered a notable amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the program has a memory leak.

```
int *in, *begin;
in = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));  /* allocate space for 1 int, at location "X" */
begin = in;
while ((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
    *in = x; 
    in++;    /* "in" increments address (to location) "X+1" */
    in = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); /* address "X+1" is lost as malloc returns  
                                        a different memory location, *not*
                                        necessarily at "X+2". Access to 
                                        previous data other than pointed to by 
                                        "begin" is lost */
}

*in = '\0';  /* this makes probably more senese than assigining EOF here */
```

There needs to be corresponding calls to `free()` when you allocate memory.

Also, I don't think the input is stored correctly.

`in` is *never* given a ***continious*** block of memory to store the data.  Instead a single memory location of size to store an `int` is repeatedly allocated and assigned to `in`, but we don't really know where this memory is, so all of these allocations are lost since only a single pointer `in` is keeping track of them.

In other words, the leak consists of repeatedly allocating memory for the size of an `int`, assigning it to `in`, and then losing any reference to that location next time through the loop.

Variable `begin` initially points at the first item entered, but then subsequently trapses through unknown memory as its pointer value is  incremented by 1 repeatedly in the output loop.

A better approach would be to allocate a single, larger *continuous* buffer once at the start and then use it as you increment your `in` pointer, or to start with a smaller amount but then monitor memory use and `realloc()` more as needed (but much more overhead to save a few byes of memory).

Also, at the end of your first loop rather than assigning `EOF` to `in`, it would make more sense to put in a null character.

Finally, the `free(in)` call at the bottom of the program frees only a single memory location, none of the other previously allocated memory.

Here's a quickly put together version that works, I tried to make *minimal changes to the original code* and to *keep your code structure intact* (I am sure you had your reasons for writing it this way with two loops in the first place) though this could be written much more compactly with just one loop.

Note I initially allocate space for 100 characters, adjust this according to your needs, or alternatively allocate less initially, but then keep track of memory consumption and `realloc()` more memory as you need (which I think was your initial intention, but just not implemented quite correctly).

```
int main(void) {
    int x;
    int *in, *begin;
    int *start_loc;
    in = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 100); /* continious space */
    begin = in;
    start_loc = in; /* keep track of start location for final free() call */

    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
        *in = x;
        in++;
    }
    *in = 0;  /* terminator for the input string/data */

    while (*begin != 0) {   /* simplified */
        putchar(*begin);
        begin++;
    }

    free(start_loc);  /* free allocated memory */
    return 0;
}
```

This could be written without the use of a new variable `start_loc` (by reusing `in` for instance) but I chose to write it this way to emphasize the importance of keeping track of the start of your memory allocation and the ability to correctly free memory allocated, so to address your memory leak problem.

Comment: I don't think I'm losing the location every time I allocate a byte. Because in the second while loop, I'm able to receive the exact same sequence of characters by incrementing `begin`.

Comment: @Babkock You don't have any guarantee that `malloc` returns continuous addresses in memory to you between separate requests (perhaps it does as a fluke here, but it's not guaranteed)

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a memory leak, for every call to `malloc` there sould be a corresponding call to `free` in your program.

In your program `malloc` is called several times but there is only one call to `free`.

Comment: Where should I put the corresponding `free` statements? Whenever I put them in a loop parallel to the loop with `malloc` statements, my terminal gives me about 50 `malloc` errors.

Comment: Using `malloc` multiple times for a single `int` is inefficient as `malloc` is a consuming function. You should allocate directly an array of `int`, for example 128 `int` or more. Then `free` your object as soon as you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

Levon's answer is correct.  You increase the value of `in` here:

```
in++;
```

...but then you reassign it to an address that is arbitrary here:

```
in = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

To achieve what you're trying to do you either need to:

- Allocate a large chunk of contiguous memory in one go, and realloc() whenever it needs to expand (this is what you're trying to achieve), or;
- Use linked lists to navigate through a list of non-contiguous memory addresses (this is what you've actually managed to write).

Answer (score 0):

When you use malloc to allocate memory, you should make sure that the pointer which point to the memory is not NULL, and after you free the memory, you are better to set the pointer to NULL